# Adding updatepanel trigger on button causes isvalid to return false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a file upload control and a required validator and regular expression validator for validating the file upload control. When I click the upload button, I want a dropdown in an update panel to reflect newly uploaded file. Therefore I have added AsyncPostBackTrigger in update panel for the Upload button. Unfortunately it is causing IsValid property to return false in my code-behind file. When I remove trigger, IsValid returns true. Any resolution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my own question. Instead of AsyncPostBackTrigger I added PostBackTrigger and my issue was resolved.